# Swift Xcode Switching between View Controllers - Navigation between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift4

I'm using Firebase in my app, and every time user launches the app - I need to check if the person is logged in. And if the user is logged in - I need the Home View Controller to be opened, if the user isn't logged in - I need to open the Log In View Controller. How do I implement it in my mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the Firebase Documentation, and if you see carefully enough, there is a function to get the current user email ID and the custom ID allocated to the user by FireBase. If these 2 parameters are nil when you start up your app(in your first screen), then you can performSegue(xx,yy). else you can directly go to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean User Default in your app to keep track if user has already logged in before. If  true then you can navigate to Home View controller else navigate to Log in view controller. You can find more details on User Defaults [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults) and [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)